# Uiactivityindicator not showing in subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to show a spinner in a subview on a tableview controller on my main thread. The view is only showing on occasions and generally appears to be showing after my background thread has finished. Here is my code:

```
[self.view addSubview:spinnerView];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:spinnerView];
        self.spinnerView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
        self.spinnerView.center = CGPointMake(160, 150);

        [spinner startAnimating];

        dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("downloader", NULL);
        dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^ {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10];
                // Add recurring transactions if necessary
                if (tran.recur.id != 0) {
                    [Utilities addRecurringTransactionsUpToCurrentMonthByTransaction:tran];
                }

                [spinner stopAnimating];
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            });
        });
        dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an Xcode question.

Answer (score 0):

Since all UI is running on main thread, you must call performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: like below:

```
    [self.view addSubview:spinnerView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:spinnerView];
    self.spinnerView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    self.spinnerView.center = CGPointMake(160, 150);

    [spinner performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startAnimating) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];


    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("downloader", NULL);
    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^ {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10];
            // Add recurring transactions if necessary
            if (tran.recur.id != 0) {
                [Utilities addRecurringTransactionsUpToCurrentMonthByTransaction:tran];
            }

            [spinner performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        });
    });
    dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
```

Comment: This behaves exactly the same as before. The Spinner work is currently on the main thread.